# PNGs at 400.997 PPI and need them at 401 PPI

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, png, ppi

I'm having an issue right now where I'm trying to get my designer to send over icons at 401 PPI. My designer says he is exporting my icons at 401 PPI but when I receive them I open them up in Photoshop and Illustrator on various computers and they are showing 400.99 (or 400.997)

Anyone have any insight on why this is happening?

Comment: If you need an icon; aka for electronic device; you do not need any ppi at all.

Comment: is 1/100th of a pixel causing issues?

Answer (score 2):

PNG does not have a PPI value container. It has a `pHYs` chunk that measures pixels per meter. In combination with roundtripping between meters and inches and floating point restrictions that is as close as you can get it to report a resolution of 401 ppi.

All that really matters is that you have correct number of pixels though. PNG is not meant for print applications and the resolution is pretty meaningless in other uses.

Its possible that the data is written in a text chunk also in adition to the phys chunk. But your viewer might not be aware of this. Or it may be omitted. But like i said its pretty meaningless.